# What is the easiest way to convert a file into a WCF compatible stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What would be the easiest way to convert a user selected file (.txt, .htm, .bmp, .jpg etc.) into a Stream so that it can be sent to a service (WCF)?

Answer (score 1):

The [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc65tk0x.aspx) methods all return a `FileStream` that inherits from `Stream`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to open a read-only stream.

```
FileStream yourStream = new FileInfo("Path.to.file").OpenRead();
```